# How do I set an SNTP server through the Windows API?

Tags: winapi, ntp

I'd like to configure Windows programmatically to use a user-specified SNTP server. Is there a function in the Windows API for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through the registry:

- [Registry entries for the W32Time service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223184)
- [Configuring the Time Service: NtpServer and SpecialPollInterval](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2008/02/26/configuring-the-time-service-ntpserver-and-specialpollinterval.aspx)

Alternatively, you could interact with the [W32tm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx) console utility.

The Date and Time control panel (timedate.cpl) does this with a call to `W32TimeSetConfig` from w32time.dll, but that appears to do nothing but set the `NtpServer` value in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters`.

Comment: [How the Windows Time Service Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773013%28v=ws.10%29): _The W32Time service is not a full-featured NTP solution that meets time-sensitive application needs and is not supported by Microsoft as such. For more information, see Microsoft Knowledge Base article 939322_: [Support boundary to configure the Windows Time service for high accuracy environments](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us)